# Consultar por MES/AÑO con datetimepicker a SQLServer usando php

Tags: php, jquery, datetimepicker

Buenas estoy usando PHP(MVC) con PDO, estoy  tratando de realizar una consulta por mes y año desde la vista usando datetimpicker.  Pero no consigo que me devuelva los de la db, lo estoy realizando de la siguiente manera.

mi formuarlio es el siguiente:

```
<input type="text" id="txtMes" name="txtMes" placeholder="" class="form-control input-sm" style="texttransform:uppercase;" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();">
```

mi archivo javascript es el siguiente:

```
function buscar_datos()
{
 var mes = $("#txtMes").val();

    if(mes!="")
    {
        $.ajax({

           type:"GET",
           url:"web/ajax/reload-creditos_mes.php?mes="+mes,
           success: function(data){
              $('#reload-div').html(data);
           }

       });

    } else {
            $.ajax({

           type:"GET",
           url:"web/ajax/reload-creditos_mes.php?mes=empty",
           success: function(data){
              $('#reload-div').html(data);
           }

       });
    }
}
```

mi archivo reload-creditos_mes.php es el siguiente, donde tengo que pasar el parametro obtenido del formulario.

```
<?php
                                        $filas = $objGarantia->ctrListarInventarioMes($mes);
    
                                            //$filas = $objGarantia->ctrListarInventarioMes('MES', $mes, '', 1);
                                            if (is_array($filas) || is_object($filas)) {
                                                foreach ($filas as $row => $column) {
                                                    $fecha_otorgamiento = $column['cre_fecha_otorgamiento'];
                                                    if (is_null($fecha_otorgamiento)) {
                                                        $c_fecha_otorgamiento = '';
                                                    } else {
                                                        $c_fecha_otorgamiento = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $fecha_otorgamiento)->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
                                                    } ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><?php echo $column['CODIGOCREDITO']; ?></td>
                                                    
                                                    <td><?php echo $column['NOMBRE']; ?></td>
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    <td><?php echo $column['MONTO']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $column['AGENCIA']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $column['PLAZO']; ?></td>
                                                     ?>
```

mi contolador es el siguiente

```
public function ctrListarInventarioMes($mes)
{
    $filas = GarantiaModel::mdlInventarioGarantiaConsultaMES($mes);
}
```

el modelo es el siguiente, no se si aqui tengo el error de recibir el parametro y obtener los resultados devueltos en mi consulta.

omite gran parte de la consulta y puse despues del where, alguna sugerencia de como resolverlo.

```
public static function mdlInventarioGarantiaConsultaMES($mes)
    {
        $dbconec = Conexion::Conectar();
        try {
           // $month = 5;
           // $year = 2021;
            $year = date('Y', strtotime($mes));

            $month = date('F', strtotime($mes));

           $result = [];
            $query = "SELECT
            cli_identificacion AS CUI,
            CONCAT(cli_nombre1,' ',cli_nombre2,' ',cli_apellido1,' ',cli_apellido2) AS NOMBRE,
            cre_credito AS CODIGOCREDITO,
            ofi_nombre AS AGENCIA,
            CONVERT(varchar,cre_fecha_otorgamiento,23) AS FECHA_OTORGAMIENTO,
            cre_plazo AS PLAZO,
            --edad cliente
      FROM
            CREDITO.dbo.GR_GARANTIAS AS a
            INNER JOIN CREDITO.dbo.CR_CREDITOS AS b
      WHERE
           --cre_fecha_otorgamiento BETWEEN ? AND ?
            MONTH(?) AND YEAR(?)
            AND
            gar_estado = 'C'
            AND g.dir_tipo_direccion = 'D' AND g.dir_estado = 'A' --AND cre_credito='2103INM000252-F3'
            AND f.estado IN(0,1)
      ORDER BY
            gar_cliente";

            $stmt = $dbconec->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute([$mes,$year,$month]);
            //$stmt->execute();

            $count = $stmt->rowCount();

            if ($count != 0) {
                return $stmt->fetchAll();
            }

            $dbconec = null;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo '<span class="label label-danger label-block">ERROR AL CARGAR LOS DATOS, PRESIONE F5</span>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: En cuanto a tu problema concreto, no veo como recoges el dato en `reload-creditos_mes.php`.  Parece que te falta un `$mes = $_GET['mes'];` al principio del archivo, antes de usar la variable `$mes`.  Ponlo y prueba a ver que te falta luego.

Comment: Bien entiendo y pido disculpas, pero si en el archivo reload-creditos_mes.php si ando recibiendo por GET : https://pastebin.com/nq1fvgrM

Comment: Diria que esto lo tienes bien: `$mes = isset($_GET['mes']) ? $_GET['mes'] : '';` pero esto mal: `if ($mes == 'empty') {`   supongo que deberia ser `if ($mes == '') {` mas bien, porque sino lo estas comparando la cadena `empty` (o bien puedes usar `ìf(empty($mes)) {` seguramente)

Comment: Y deberias meter ese código tambien en la pregunta, sino se lo tendras que ir diciendo uno a uno a los que pretendan darte solución

Comment: sigue sin funcionar, intentare quemando la data.